# All plugins are not shown in android studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

No plugins are shown, in browse repositories. No proxy settings set etc. Tried setting repository url but no work. Screenshot is attached for reference. Only 1 plugin is shown. Tried invalidate caches and restart also.

[image]

Version: Android Studio 3.3 Canary 3

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. Updating Android Studio to 3.3 Canary 4 solved the problem. Now all plugins are shown.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using Android Studio 4.0.
Adding the following repository url solved the problem.

Steps:

1. File > Settings > Search for 'plugins'
2. Click on the cog icon > Manage plugin repositories
3. Add the url: https:// plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio

It is also good to mention that if you're using a proxy you should configure it on Http Proxy setting (same cog icon menu)

If this does not work for you, there is another thread on jetbrains comunity with additional instructions. Keep an eye on it:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008086019-Android-Studio-Plugins-marketplace-not-working